# Call the div displaying error message only when error occurs

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In this code I am displaying errors with `javascript` and in case `javascript` is disabled `php` will work, error messages are displayed by `div` at the bottom so whether error occurs or not, div will always be there, though message is displayed only when there is error. I want that the `div` should be called only when error occurs because it is causing problems to style error message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            var title = $('#title').val();
            var body = $('#body').val();
            if(title.length<5) {
                $('#er').html('Error mesg');
                return false;
            }
            if(body.length<500) {
                $('#er').html('error msg');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
    error_reporting('E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $title=$_POST['title'];
        $body=$_POST['body'];
        if (strlen($title) < 5) {
           $er = "Title must be of minimum 5 characters";
        }
        else if (strlen($body) <500 ) {
           $er = "Body must be of minimum 500 characters";
        }
        else {
      // pdo statement to insert data in db

        if ($statement->rowCount() == 1) {
           $er = "Congratulations, successfully posted.";
        }
        else {
           print_r($db->errorInfo());
        }
    }
}?> 

<form action="" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Write post</legend>
<label>Title:</label> 
<input type="text" name="title" id="title"><br />
<label>Body:</label> 
<textarea name="body" id="body"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="er"><?php echo $er; ?></div>
```

I tried replacing `div` with this code below, but now no error message is displayed seems there is no `div`

```
<?php
if(!empty($er)) {
  echo '<div id="er">'.$er.'</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: please share your html

Comment: there is only `div` for displaying error and its at bottom none other for displaying code , other is just simple form type

Comment: where is your #title, #body, #submit...mean to say your form

Comment: javascript click function will work and error msg will be Error mesg..but if you comment out the click function your php code will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Just try replacing the `php` part

```
<?php
    if($er) {
       echo '<div id="er">'.$er.'</div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: no the code doesn't work at all on clicking submit no errors are displayed its nearly same as code i tried so behaves similarly

Answer (score 0):

You may have defined `$er` somewhere in the code. Because of this `if ($er) { // show hide div code }` not responding.

Or try to define `$er = null` or `$er = ""` at top of the document and show error div if `$er != null` or `$er != ""`

```
$er = null;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   // your code
}
```

At html

```
if ($er != null) {
   echo "<div id='er'> $er </div>";
}
```